# UIAlertController move to another controller on alert action - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I'm trying to move to another controller on alert view action. It's moving to next controller as expected, but once it moved to another controller, again it's showing the same alert. Please check the below code.

```
func decode(decodedURL: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Confirm", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FormViewController") as? FormViewController
    viewController?.fillData(dataDic: convertJsonStringToDictionary(jsonString: decodedURL))

    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action) in       
        self.navigationController?.show(viewController!, sender: true)
    }


    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        print("You've pressed cancel");       
    }

    alertController.addAction(action1)
    alertController.addAction(action2)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Calling above method  below

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
    if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
        messageLabel.text = "No code detected"
        return
    }
    // Get the metadata object.
    let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
    if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
        // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata (or barcode) then update the status label's text and set the bounds
        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds
        if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            decode(decodedURL: metadataObj.stringValue!)
            messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having one alertview with ok and cancel button.

Comment: In which function of the current viewController is this code executed?

Comment: @regina_fallangi this alerview comes on top of camera. And the method executes from   func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {} .

Comment: I am asking under the assumption that someone `metadataOutput` gets called again somehow, so it'd be good to have the complete trail of logic that ends up in the code you posted being called. Would you mind adding that? Just the important part.

Comment: If you use perform segue then it may work

Comment: @regina_fallangi I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: I don't see where in `metaDataOutput` you are calling `decode(decodedURL:)`. Please check your update and compare with original code.

Comment: @regina_fallangi check now

Comment: Where is `metaDataOutput` being called? What the *complete* trail. Does `FormViewController` have a parent class? Are `FormViewController` and the current controller connected in any way?

Comment: @Mac_Play, If i am not wrong. metadataOutput function can be called multiple time . until you called captureSession?.stopRunning()
        captureSession = nil

Comment: @regina_fallangi **metaDataOutput** is the delegate method of AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjects

Comment: metadataOutput is delegate func of AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate. It continue get called until you stop it.

Comment: I suggest adding a breakpoint inside metadata and proving that is obviously being called after you push the new controller.

Comment: @AnandMishra you are right. It's calling multiple times whenever the detection happens. If I make the capture session immediately after detection will it works?

Comment: @AnandMishra Which will be the best place to stop the capture session? Can you please shed some more light?

Comment: Yes ,write like it, 
 if (//required scan complete) {
                  captureSession?.stopRunning()
        captureSession = nil
}
In side metaDataOutPut

Comment: @AnandMishra Thanks, it's working great.

Comment: @regina_fallangi Thanks for your input as well.

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'AVMetadataFaceObject' (0x1b245bd28) to 'AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject' (0x1b245be68). Getting this error often, any idea?

Answer (score 3):

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

is delegate function of

> AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate

. It continue get called until your captureSession is alive.

So When you navigate to next screen just stop captureSession.

```
captureSession?.stopRunning() 
captureSession = nil
```

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'AVMetadataFaceObject' (0x1b245bd28) to 'AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject' (0x1b245be68). Getting this error often, any idea?